# How can I add a class to a div in order to change background color?

Tags: html, css

So, I have a simple login page that has a light green background, and would like to change the background color to a light red when the 'loginbox' div with id = 'loginbox' also has a class 'error'. My page looks as follows:

[VALID HTML http://i1154.photobucket.com/albums/p525/covertcj/ScreenShot2012-01-16at20759PM.png](http://i1154.photobucket.com/albums/p525/covertcj/ScreenShot2012-01-16at20759PM.png)

with the relavent HTML looking like:

HTML (Before adding error class):

```html
<div id="loginbox">
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input>

    <span>Password:</span>
    <input>

    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

With the CSS given below, I feel that this should work; however, when adding the error class to the div, nothing happens.

CSS:

```css
#loginbox {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    background: #EBFFEF; 
}
#loginbox .error {
    background: #FFEBEB; 
}
#loginbox input {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    width: 190px;
    float: right;
}
#loginbox span {
    height: 15px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    float: left;
}
#loginbox button {
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: right; 
}
```

HTML (After after error class):

```html
<div class="error" id="loginbox">
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input>

    <span>Password:</span>
    <input>

    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Am I possibly misusing this technique? Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris Covert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect: `#loginbox .error` is selecting all elements with class `error` *contained within* the element selected by `#loginbox`. This works exactly the same way that `#loginbox input` works - You're selecting `input` elements *within* the `#loginbox` div.

To refine a selector with additional class/attribute selectors, you need to chain them together *without whitespace*. In your specific example, remove the space and use:

```
#loginbox.error { ... }
```

Always remember, seperating your selectors by whitespace means you're selecting *nested tags*.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
#loginbox .error {
```

The #loginbox has class .error, so you need to target that with no space between:

```
#loginbox.error {
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loginbox" class="error">
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input>

    <span>Password:</span>
    <input>

    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work just fine if you change

```
#loginbox .error
```

to

```
#loginbox.error
```

Adding a space means you are styling a sub-element of `#loginbox`. With no space, we are selecting the `<div />` with id `loginbox` AND having the class `error`